# Variable name in command to change in every loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command that sets a variable's value in a Do until loop and I want this command to refer to a different variable each time (e.g. "datapoint1" in the first loop, "datapoint2" in the second, etc.). I tried to use a "For" loop instead of "Do Until", but that creates a problem as the times that I want the loop to be performed fluctuates a lot (the "Do Until" loop is part of a larger "For" loop).

So my question is: Is there a way to make that single command line to refer to different variables in each loop?

I have a sample of my code below for reference. Thank you all in advance for your help.

```
 Dim datapoint(0 to 15) As Integer

        Do Until hello = 1
        rw = False
        h = h + 1 'I have tried to use this variable to count the number of each loop.
        name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Text
        level = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Text
        If InStr(name, fullname) > 0 Then 'Checks if the line contains data for a specific name
            If level = "High" Then: datapoint(h) = ActiveCell.Value ' This creates an error
            Set r = ActiveCell
            Do Until rw = True
            Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
            If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                r.Select
                rw = True
            End If
            Loop

        Else

            hello = 1
        End If
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). • Please also tell which errors you get.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Pᴇʜ, I will have a look at the thread you've shared. The error I get is: Run-time error '6': Overflow.

Basically, I think that the h that is within the parentheses is not taking the value of the variable h.

Comment: Note that `datapoint` is only defined for `0 To 15` so if your `h` is  `>15` it will throw an "Overflow" error. Check the value of `h` in case of error. Also your `datapoint` is of type `Integer` so the maximum value can be `32767`. If you try to write bigger values from `ActiveCell.Value` then you get an overflow too. So also check the value in `ActiveCell.Value` in case of error.

Comment: Solved! The error was occurring because the cell value was greater than 32767. Thank you for your help Pᴇʜ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `datapoint` is only defined for `0 To 15` so if your `h` is `>15` it will throw an "Overflow" error. Check the value of `h` in case of error. Also your datapoint is of type `Integer` so the maximum value can be `32767`.

If you try to write bigger values from `ActiveCell.Value` then you get an overflow too. So also check the value in `ActiveCell.Value` in case of error.

If you use values greater than that you must use another type:

```
Dim datapoint(0 to 15) As Long    'for bigger integer values
Dim datapoint(0 to 15) As Double  'for decimal values
```